# Incorrect images paths when ng build -prod is deployed in a subfolder of a webserver

Tags: angular

first of all i need to say that i just started working with angular and i dont understand whats the problem.

I have a header component with a link to an image

```
<span><img src="./assets/images/logo.png" routerLink="" height="92" width="268"/></span>
```

When i run **ng serve** the image is shown in the browser. When i build a production version with **ng build --prod** its generating a dist folder everything fine so far. When i upload all the files within dist folder to a subfolder on my webserver the image links are broken. Within the index.html file i manually updated the base tag to

```
<base href="/subfolder/">
```

When i hit **www.myDomain/subfolder/index.html** i see my page without the images.

When i inspect the link of the image in my headerComponent it looks like that:

```
<img _ngcontent-c1="" routerlink="" src="../assets/images/logo.png" tabindex="0" width="268" height="92">
```

Of course i can move the dist folder one level up and the problem is solved but is their maybe a better way to configure the angular project?

Comment: Try running `ng build --prod --base-href="../"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a **fast fix only**, in your *dist* folder, update your Index.html file to `<base href="./">`

**The right way** to do it, is by configuring your `angular.json` file to *build* and *serve* to different `baseHref`:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "Your-Project-Name": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "baseHref": "./",
            ...
          },
          ...
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "baseHref": "/",
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me to fix that problem